# error using 2D pointers

Tags: c++

i'm new to this site, so please excuse me if i ask my question in a wrong way.

For my programmation course, i've been asked to code a function which will give me the product of two square matrices (3x3) using pointers.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
    //This function make a LxC matrix out of a double pointer
void matrixMake(double **a,int unsigned l,int unsigned c)
{
    a=new double*[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        a[i]=new double[c];
    }
}
//This function returns a random number between a and b
double randU(double a=0.0,double b=10.0)
{
    double x=(double)(rand()/RAND_MAX);
    return(a*x+b*(1-x));
}

//This is the function that seems to be a problem, this function creates a matrix and fills it with random numbers between 0 and 10.
double ** matrixGen()
{
    double **matrix;
    matrixMake(matrix,3,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
        {
            matrix[i][n]=randU();
        }
    }
    return(matrix);
}
```

It compiles fine except when i run the program, it gives me an ugly segmentation error.
I tried debugging it, it crashes when it runs the line `matrix[i][n]=randU();` is executed.

It didn't give you the full code, the rest is irrelevant to my question and seems to work fine.

I hope my question is not too dumb ^^... Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: The matrix make function hast to take the pointer by reference (`double **&a`). Otherwise, `makeMatrix` will not change the `matrix`variable in `matrixGen` so  `matrix[i][n]` is accessing some random memory location.

Comment: Also one piece of advice: Using pointers to pointers and dynamically allocated c-arrays this is porbably the worst possible way to handle 3x3 Matrices in c++, but if you are required to do so by your teacher...

Comment: Your randU function will always return `b`. See my answer below to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because when you pass in `double **matrix` to your `matrixMake` function, the memory address is copied, so anything you do to a inside that function will not stick to `double **matrix` in your main function.

you could try this:

```
double ** matrixMake(int unsigned l,int unsigned c)
{
    double ** a;
    a=new double*[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        a[i]=new double[c];
    }

    return a;
}
```

and inside your main function have

```
double **matrix = matrixMake(3,3);
```

instead of

```
double **matrix;
matrixMake(matrix,3,3);
```

you can also try to pass in `double**` to your `matrixMake` either by pointer or by reference, but that would make you a 3 star programmer, which is not a good thing. it would look like this anyway:

```
void matrixMake(double ***a,int unsigned l,int unsigned c)
{
    *a=new double*[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        *a[i]=new double[c];
    }
}
```

and instead of `matrixMake(matrix,3,3);` in your code you would have `matrixMake(&matrix,3,3);`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to correcting the signature of `matrixMake`:

```
void matrixMake(double**& a, unsigned l, unsigned c)
```

You should also correct this:

> `double x=(double)(rand()/RAND_MAX);` // x always evaluates to zero

into this:

```
double x=((double)rand())/RAND_MAX);
```

Comment: Yup, thank you, but why exactly will rand()/RAND_MAX will always evaluate to zero? is it because rand() is an integer?

Comment: yes, both the numerator and the denominator are integers, so the parenthesized expression `(rand()/RAND_MAX)` is integer division, zero because num < denom. Casting it *later* to double wont help. You should cast one of them to `double` before the division, in order to get `double division`.

Comment: Okay, it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void matrixMake(double **a,int unsigned l,int unsigned c)
{
    a=new double*[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        a[i]=new double[c];
    }
}
```

This function takes a pointer in by value, and then immediately assigns to it, ignoring the value that was passed in. If you want to modify the pointer, you need to either pass it in by reference (`double**&`), or by pointer (`double***`). Or you could just return a fresh pointer from the function, since its value doesn't depend upon what was passed in.

```
double** matrixMake(int unsigned l,int unsigned c)
{
    double** a=new double*[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        a[i]=new double[c];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: @ColinEvrard: `double**&`, not `double&**`.

Comment: Read it from right to left. (`&`)Reference to (`*`) pointer to (`*`) pointer to double.

Comment: yup, just seen it sorry :$